# Kivy installation does not find GL/gl.h?

Tags: python, kivy

i just wanted to install kivy to test it and make some apps
i installed cython and the other things
then i typed into the terminal (ubuntu 12.04):

```
sudo easy_install kivy
```

as answer i got this:

```
Searching for kivy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/kivy/
Best match: Kivy 1.2.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/K/Kivy/Kivy-1.2.0.tar.gz#md5=468da8a353c2ea4936eb92d71403c960
Processing Kivy-1.2.0.tar.gz
Running Kivy-1.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rcrkeK/Kivy-1.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-xdOqxi
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.2.0
WARNING: GLES 2.0 headers are not found
Fallback to Desktop opengl headers.
Build configuration is:
 * use_opengl_es2  =  False
 * use_glew  =  False
 * use_opengl_debug  =  False
 * use_mesagl  =  False
Generate config.h
Generate config.pxi
In file included from /tmp/easy_install-rcrkeK/Kivy-1.2.0/kivy/graphics/texture.c:273:0:
/tmp/easy_install-rcrkeK/Kivy-1.2.0/kivy/graphics/gl_redirect.h:38:22: fatal error: GL/gl.h: El fitxer o directori no existeix
compilation terminated.
 error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

did i something wrong? or do i need to install something?

P.S. sorry for the catalan El fitxer o directori no existeix means File not found.

Comment: Have you followed the installation guide on Kivy documentation? http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install libgl1-mesa-dev package through apt. Also maybe you would wish to look on building instructions at launchpad:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kivy-team/kivy/packaging/view/head:/debian/control

Comment: Solved my problem! :D

Yay!

Comment: This also solved my problem, however that link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to install mesa-common-dev, also see: [Debian packages search](http://packages.debian.org/search?mode=path&suite=squeeze&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=GL/gl.h).
If you have a Nvidia card, you may need to install nvidia-glx-dev.
You may experiment the same issue with the file `glut.h`, which is included in freeglut3-dev. Again, see [the Debian packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?mode=path&suite=squeeze&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=glut.h) which contain that file.

Comment: You can try to download kivy from PyPI and running `python setup.py install` to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Lol... Python is used by many programs, so if you delete files arbitrarily it is very likely you mess up the whole installation.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO! Answers typically do better on this site when you provide both a code solution and an explanation that goes along with it :)